# Updating a jira issue with the rest api. NOT soap

Tags: php, rest, curl, jira

my php function to update jira issue is like this.i have hardcoded the issue id.it generates an error in `if (property_exists($result, 'errors'))`. saying parameter is not an object.

```
function post_to($resource, $data) {
$jdata = json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
CURLOPT_POST => 1,
CURLOPT_URL => JIRA_URL . '/rest/api/latest/' . $resource,
CURLOPT_USERPWD => USERNAME . ':' . PASSWORD,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $jdata,
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type: application/json'),
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return json_decode($result);
}

function create_issue($issue) {
return post_to('issue/10224/editmeta', $issue);
}

$new_issue = array(
    'update' =>array(
        'fields' => array(
            'project' => array('key' => 'DOTNET'),
            'summary' => 'Test via REST',
            'description' => 'Description of issue goes here.',
            'issuetype' => array('name' => 'Task')
            ))
);

$result = create_issue($new_issue);
if (property_exists($result, 'errors')) {
echo "Error(s) creating issue:\n";
var_dump($result);
                }
            }
```

what am i doing wrong here? please answer.

Comment: try changing `return json_decode($result);` to `return print_r($result);die();` and add the output. thanks!

Comment: HTTP Status 405 - Method Not Allowed
any luck?

Comment: I'd test this on a plain local instance on my machine, then check I have permission to create such an issue in the browser on the real machine. Can you use REST methods that retrieve the data from the real machine?

Comment: No @mdoar
i cannot even try the url on the browser.it doesnt show anything.only a 405 method not allowed message.and i can create issues in the specified project in the hosted jira

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure, let's try some thing:

change

```
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type: application/json'),
```

to:

```
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);
```

and:

```
$new_issue = array(
    'update' =>array(
        'fields' => array(
            'project' => array('key' => 'DOTNET'),
            'summary' => 'Test via REST',
            'description' => 'Description of issue goes here.',
            'issuetype' => array('name' => 'Task')
            ))
);
```

to:

```
$new_issue = array(
    'fields' => array(
        'project' => array('key' => 'DOTNET'),
        'summary' => 'Test via REST',
        'description' => 'Description of issue goes here.',
        'issuetype' => array('name' => 'Task')
     )
);
```

lastly, change:

```
CURLOPT_URL => JIRA_URL . '/rest/api/latest/' . $resource,
```

to your real address, as well as writing `2` instead of `latest`, i.e.:

```
CURLOPT_URL=>'http://localhost/rest/api/2/issue/',
```

try this, and let me know how it's goes, good luck!

**EDIT**

try changing:

```
CURLOPT_POST => 1,
```

to:

```
CURL_POST=>true,
CURLOPT_VERBOSE=>1,
```

btw, where is your jira server? didn't you say it was hosted? `localhost:8080` will work only if Jira is installed locally. If so, try opening it using a browser  `http://localhost:8084/rest/api/2/issue/`

**EDIT 2**

Make sure the `Allow Remote API Calls` is turned ON under Administration > General Configuration.

to update an issue:

the URL should point to the soon-to-be-updated issue, i.e.:

```
http://localhost/rest/api/2/issue/TEST-31
```

and the data should be the same as before, meaning:

```
$new_issue = array(
    'fields' => array(
        'project' => array('key' => 'DOTNET'),
        'summary' => 'Test via REST',
        'description' => 'Description of issue goes here.',
        'issuetype' => array('name' => 'Task')
     )
);
```

just as you wrote when you tried to create an issue. you can find [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+API+Example+-+Edit+issues) some simple example of how to do so.

**EDIT 3**

Are you sure you have the right jira address? try again opening a browser and going to the URL and compare it to [this example](https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/2/issue/JRA-9). If the page won't show, you will have to contact [Jira's support](https://answers.atlassian.com) and ask them how come you can't access the hosted Jira remote API.

Comment: Nope nothing..im using this url.
http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/issue/10224/editmeta
this is right?
i think return $result contain empty array. know why?

Comment: yes we have it hosted.. but i used this to test my app..if something went wrong in that..you can imagine what will happend..lol...
and yes i tried it in browser and it displayed all the issues in a json..
and i tried your update
its generating a error
Warning: First parameter must either be an object or the name of an existing class in G:\Drupal\xampp\htdocs\imap\move.php on line 57
its referring to the (property_exists($result, 'errors'))

Comment: :) so that's that. `localhost` is getting to your own machine, and once it doesn't find Jira, it fails. Try connecting to your real Jira (you can create a test project) or download jira locally for development.

Comment: nothing @Kuf...i used this same code to create an issue. and it works fine..i only edited the json array to include update attribute and the url...i think its sth wrong with the curl_setopt...but not sure

Comment: ok i will try the real thing and will let you know..thanks..:)

Comment: what URL are you using? if you type is in a browser, do you get a page?

Comment: hey @Kuf my hosted server uses a https..is that a prob?

Comment: no, as long as the `Allow Remote API Calls` option is turned ON. the page should show.

Comment: Hey @Kuf
its not working.even the create new issue function is not working aswell.but it works in the localhost not in the real server.

Comment: is `Allow Remote API Calls option` is turned ON? are you sure you have the right jira adderess? try again opening a browser and going to the URL, you should get [the same page as this](https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/2/issue/JRA-9). If you don't, you will have to contact [Jira's support](https://answers.atlassian.com) and ask them how come you can't access the hosted Jira remote API.

Comment: im using a ondemand version. does that change anything? no i dont get anything. only a access not allowed error..sigh..i'll try. thanks man

Comment: that's weird since the `ondemmand` suppose to support the API call by default. just make sure the `Allow Remote API Calls` is turned ON under Administration > General Configuration.

Comment: the name might be little different, just allow any remote API calls in the `General Configuration`

Comment: sorry...yes that gives me the json of that issue..whats wrong in this? i have tried everything..i can access the issue by typing it in the browser. but cant create anything..and its turned on aswell..

Comment: just to make sure, when logging to Jira using the user and password your script uses, can you open an issue? (same type you try to open using the script)

Comment: hey @Kuf
thanks for all your help. i got it to working. found a great class file in github that does all what i need. and it was a error with the ssl. in https we have to call curl in a different way..:) thanks for all your help..

Comment: hey @Kuf i have posted a question.can you take a look at that..thanks
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14108563/updating-status-in-jira-via-php

Answer (score 1):

***editmeta*** should be used only to OBTAIN meta data from an issue.

To update an issue you must use the ***issue*** method.

You can check the Jira API details here: 
https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/#api/2/