# updating status in jira via php

Tags: php, rest, jira

im using a email client that i build to update jira tasks. i have managed to change the assignee and the summary through it. but i cannot seems to find a way to update the status. following is the code i used.

```
$resolution->id="4";
$update->transitions= array($resolution);
$queryIssue = new Jira($config);
$queryIssue->updateTransition($query,$update);
```

the class:

```
public function updateTransition($issueKey,$json){
$this->request->openConnect('https://'.$this->host.'/rest/api/latest/issue/REC-143/transitions?', 'POST', $json);
$this->request->execute(); 
}
```

this gives me an error saying
`Missing 'transition' identifier`
what am i doing wrong here.please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way i input the json was incorrect.it should be,

```
$resolution->transition->id ="4";
$queryIssue->updateTransition('11205',$resolution);
```

like this. and by the way i used [this library](https://github.com/FayP/JIRA-php) to do all my needs with jira. the things which are not included here, i had to implement by my self. which is easy if you know the api urls.take a look at the rest api documentation for the suitable apis you may require.